# What is the meaning of $\operatorname{Trace}(V_\alpha)$ where $V_\alpha$ variance-covariance matrix of the MLE of $\alpha$?

Tags: experiment-design

$\newcommand{\Trace}{\operatorname{Trace}}$I am learning about design of experiments, I have been reading that minimize the variance is an important criteria for optimization. But I do not understand:

What is the meaning of $\Trace(V_\alpha)$ where $V_\alpha$ variance-covariance matrix of the MLE of $\alpha$?

Meaning in the practical sense, what this expression is saying?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The trace of a covariance matrix for a random variable is sometimes referred to as the [total variation](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~mkt/MT3732%20(MVA)/Intro.pdf) (section 1.5) of the random variable. It is an informal measure of its spread. You can also think of it as a way to characterize the variance of the RV without taking into account the covariances.

In your case, the estimator $\alpha$ is a random variable. After all, it is a function of the data! So when we discuss $V_\alpha$, we are talking about the covariance matrix of the estimator. The trace of $V_\alpha$ informs us about the overall variance of the estimate. Informally, when $\operatorname{tr}(V_\alpha)$ is high, there is a high amount of uncertainty associated with the estimate. The opposite is true when $\operatorname{tr}(V_\alpha)$ is low.

Comment: I believe "$\alpha$" in the question refers to a *vector of parameter estimates* rather than a "sample."